# How to write a value from textfield 1 to textfield 2 and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a little function in JS which will take a numerical input from textfield 1 and calculate an aspect ratio of 2/3 of it and write this value to textfield 2. Now I want the same functionality for textfield 2 but with a ratio of 3/2, so wherever the user inputs a value I want the other textfiled to be automatically filled with the calculated value.

Here is my code which works for inputting into textfiles 1 and showing 2/3 of that in textfiles 2:

```
function change()
            {    
            var ex1Val = (document.getElementById("ex1")).value;

            if (ex1Val < "0" || "9" < ex1Val)
                {
                //(document.getElementById("ex1")).value = "";
                (document.getElementById("ex1")).focus();
                return false;
                }
            else
                {
                (document.getElementById("ex2")).value = ((ex1Val * 2) / 3);
                }
            };
```

I have tried to copy the function and edit the ids and aspect ratio, but that does not work.

If not JS, Jquery will be fine, too.

Comment: I think your question has been sufficiently answered below. But here is an additional hint: Instead of `"0"` just write `0`, because `"0"` is fundamentally a string like `"abc"`. Comparing numbers with `<` is very different from comparing strings with `<`. E.g. `59 < 6` is `true` while `"59" < "6"` is `false` because string comparison first compares the first characters of the string. The `9` is in this case for the string comparison just ignored. Use `parseInt(x)` to convert `x` from a string to an integer (`parseInt("59") < parseInt("6")` is correctly `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`onInput="change(this.id)"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) event and check for id and calculate your aspect ratio.

```js
function change(id) {
  var ex1Val = (document.getElementById(id)).value;
  if (id == "ext1") {
    (document.getElementById("ext2")).value = ((ex1Val * 2) / 3);
  } else if (id === "ext2") {
    (document.getElementById("ext1")).value = ((ex1Val * 3) / 2);
  }

};
```

```html
<input id="ext1" onInput="change(this.id)" />
<input id="ext2" onInput="change(this.id)" />
```

Comment: Great. This is perfect.